The value for task ':pitest' property 'mainClass' is final and cannot be changed any further
Pi test failing with following error. Im using spring boot 2.7.18 & gradle 6.9

The value for task ':pitest' property 'mainClass' is final and cannot be changed any further.

My build.gradle contains:
apply plugin: "info.solidsoft.pitest"

    pitest {
        targetClasses = ['com.cti.stan.*']
        enableDefaultIncrementalAnalysis = true
        reportDir = file("${buildDir}/reports/pit/${project.version}")
        outputFormats = ['HTML']
        pitestVersion = '1.4.0'
        timeoutConstInMillis = 10000
        mutationThreshold = 65
        timestampedReports=false
    }

build.dependsOn 'pitest'


Please provide a build --scan URL, or at least the full error message and also including --stacktrace output.
